# Gunicorn + Django + Virtualenv + init.d service (CentOS)

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, centos6, gunicorn

Details:

```
OS = CentOS 6.6
python = 2.7.9
virtualenv = 12.1.1
gunicorn = 19.3.0
django-admin.py = 1.6.10
geonode = 2.4
```

I am trying to add a django app (geonode, http://geonode.org/) as a init.d service on CentOS 6.6 using Gunicorn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The default python for CentOS 6.6 is version 2.6, so I installed python 2.7.9 as an alternate version:

```
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
sudo tar -xzf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```

Installed setuptools, pip and virtualenv:

```
su -
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-15.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf setuptools-15.0.tar.gz
cd setuptools-15.0
python2.7 setup.py install
cd ..
rm -fr setuptools-15.0*
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python2.7 -
pip2.7 install virtualenv
```

Configured service account that will run the django application:

```
sudo mkdir -p /webapps/geonode_django/
sudo groupadd --system webapps
sudo useradd --system --gid webapps --shell /bin/bash --home /webapps/geonode_django geonode
sudo chown geonode /webapps/geonode_django/
```

Setup the virtual environment and installed python dependencies:

```
su -
su - geonode
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 .
source bin/activate
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss
pip install pycurl
pip install urlgrabber
pip install numpy
pip install pillow
pip install pastescript
pip install psycopg2
pip install gunicorn
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/G/GDAL/GDAL-1.11.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf GDAL-1.11.2.tar.gz
cd GDAL-1.11.2
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/opt/gdal-1.11.2/include/
python setup.py install
cd ..
rm -fr GDAL-1.11.2*
```

Cloned and installed the django application:

```
git clone https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode.git
cd geonode
pip install -e . --log install-geonode.log
```

Executed the required geonode (django application) commands

```
su - geonode
source bin/activate
cd geonode
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Created a script to run gunicorn:

```
mkdir /webapps/geonode_django/scripts
vim /webapps/geonode_django/scripts/gunicorn-app.sh
```

start of gunicorn-app.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd /webapps/geonode_django/geonode
source /webapps/geonode_django/bin/activate
exec /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application \
--workers=2 \
--bind=0.0.0.0:8000 \
--user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug \
--log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log 2>>/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
```

end of gunicorn-app.sh
Note: script was based off of one found here - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cspanring/4639342/raw/a44ff78aec9e1919a9e4c25886de331e787201d2/gunicorn-app.sh

```
mkdir /webapps/geonode_django/logs
chmod +x /webapps/geonode_django/scripts/gunicorn-app.sh
```

Note: I can successfully run the script as root and geonode and it displays the splash page, but when I add it to an init.d script and run it as 'service', then the result is the following:

```
[root@geonode_test ~]# curl localhost:8000
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Internal Server Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>

   </body>
</html>
```

output of gunicorn.log

```
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x7f685ecd02a8>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x7f685ed46f50>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x7f685ecd0140>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 493
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 2
  proc_name: None
  sendfile: True
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x7f685ed46de8>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x7f685ecd0848>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x7f685ecd0410>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x7f685ecd0ed8>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x7f685ecd09b0>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x7f685ecd0aa0>
  user: 496
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x7f685ecd0578>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x7f685ecd0c08>
  chdir: /webapps/geonode_django/geonode
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: geonode.wsgi:application
  errorlog: /webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x7f685ed46c80>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x7f685ecd06e0>
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:8000']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x7f685ecd0d70>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix:
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (6983)
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6992] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6992
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6993] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6993
[2015-04-15 06:48:42 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:43 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:44 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:45 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:46 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:47 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:48 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:49 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:50 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:51 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:51 +0000] [6983] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-04-15 06:48:51 +0000] [6983] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2015-04-15 06:48:51 +0000] [6992] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6992)
[2015-04-15 06:48:51 +0000] [6993] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6993)
```

output of ps aux | grep gunicorn when running as service gunicorn start

```
[root@geonode_test ~]# ps aux | grep gunicorn
root       7551  0.0  0.0 106364  1588 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /bin/sh /sbin/service gunicorn start
root       7556  0.0  0.0 108468  1688 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/gunicorn start
root       7559  0.0  0.1 163384  1976 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /bin/su   geonode /webapps/geonode_django/config/gunicorn-app.sh
geonode    7560  1.0  0.7 205892 13572 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn  geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
geonode    7569  0.3  0.9 219660 18732 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
geonode    7570  2.1  2.3 450024 44512 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
root       7576  0.0  0.0 103256   856 pts/3    S+   07:42   0:00 grep gunicorn
```

Note: this works, just not as a service
output of ps aux | grep gunicorn when running as /etc/init.d/gunicorn start

```
[root@geonode_test ~]# ps aux | grep gunicorn
root       7647  0.0  0.0 106368  1596 pts/1    S+   07:47   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/gunicorn start
root       7650  0.0  0.1 163384  1980 pts/1    S+   07:47   0:00 /bin/su geonode /webapps/geonode_django/config/gunicorn-app.sh
geonode    7651  1.3  0.7 205960 13584 pts/1    S+   07:47   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
geonode    7660  0.4  0.9 219664 18740 pts/1    S+   07:47   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
geonode    7661 10.1  4.4 414248 84380 pts/1    S+   07:47   0:00 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/python2.7 /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user=geonode --group=webapps --log-level=debug --log-file=/webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
root       7679  0.0  0.0 103256   856 pts/3    S+   07:47   0:00 grep gunicorn
```

log output:

```
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x7f390e0b72a8>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x7f390e12cf50>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x7f390e0b7140>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 493
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 2
  proc_name: None
  sendfile: True
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x7f390e12cde8>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x7f390e0b7848>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x7f390e0b7410>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x7f390e0b7ed8>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x7f390e0b79b0>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x7f390e0b7aa0>
  user: 496
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x7f390e0b7578>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x7f390e0b7c08>
  chdir: /webapps/geonode_django/geonode
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: geonode.wsgi:application
  errorlog: /webapps/geonode_django/logs/gunicorn.log
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x7f390e12cc80>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x7f390e0b76e0>
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:8000']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x7f390e0b7d70>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix:
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (7651)
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7660] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7660
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7661] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7661
[2015-04-15 07:47:27 +0000] [7651] [DEBUG] 2 workers
```

I have also tested it on a different django test app and the init service does work, so I am at a loss :(

/webapps/geonode_django/geonode/test.py

```
import os
import pprint
from wsgiref.validate import validator
import sys

from gunicorn import __version__
#@validator
def application(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""

    errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
#    pprint.pprint(('ENVIRON', environ), stream=errors)

    data = b'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data))),
        ('X-Gunicorn-Version', __version__),
        ("Test", "test тест"),
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

modified /webapps/geonode_django/scripts/gunicorn-app.sh

`exec /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn geonode.wsgi:application \`
to
`exec /webapps/geonode_django/bin/gunicorn test:application \`

Comment: Note: selinux is not blocking, netstat shows that it is listening on port 8000 when running as /etc/init.d/gunicorn start and service gunicorn start

Answer (score 2):

Gunicorn's logs were not the most helpful, out of frustration I tried uwsgi and it immediately displayed the issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "./geonode/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    from geonode.sitemap import LayerSitemap, MapSitemap
  File "./geonode/sitemap.py", line 21, in <module>
    from geonode.maps.models import Layer, Map
  File "./geonode/maps/models.py", line 35, in <module>
    from geonode.layers.models import Layer
  File "./geonode/layers/models.py", line 33, in <module>
    from geonode.base.models import ResourceBase, ResourceBaseManager, resourcebase_post_save
  File "./geonode/base/models.py", line 28, in <module>
    from geonode.utils import bbox_to_wkt
  File "./geonode/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from osgeo import ogr
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.11.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.11.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /webapps/geonode_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.11.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem
```

Finally!! Ok...so the gunicorn-app.sh needs some variables, so I added the following:

```
export GDAL_HOME=/opt/gdal-1.11.2
export GDAL_DATA=$GDAL_HOME/data
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GDAL_HOME/lib
export PATH=$GDAL_HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH
```

tested it with service gunicorn start... and it works. Well hopefully this helps someone else out.